# Making a heroku profiling tool in java

Tags: java, heroku, jvm, monitoring

I was wondering how I might develop a proper profiling to check several stuff on heroku platform . After checking heroku's site, concretely links such as : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues , I guess is really difficult to develop my own monitor because they say that is not possible to use tools as visualvm,jmap,jstats and so on. It's not possible due to the process isolation but, what does it means? If I'm not wrong, every dyno has its own jvm so we might have access to it, right?

I will be grateful if someone could tell me something about it because I've been really confused as well as there is no too much information around.

In the other hand I've been checking the new relic add-on in my heroku app and it's working properly but I need to connect to heroku dashboard to check it so I'd like to avoid this kind of actions and make my own dashboard to know how percentage of processor is being using, memory, http requests ( even though tools like alertra o nagios might be used in teh future) between internal process in heroku (I got several dyno webs and dyno workers).

I hope you'll understand my goals,  I've been searching a lot about it but I was unlucky.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not possible to use tools such as `visualvm`, `jmap`, `jstat`, etc is that they require connecting to TCP ports on the JVM, but dynos only allow incoming connections on a single allocated HTTP port specified in the assigned `$PORT` environment variable.

You are correct that each Java app on Heroku has its own JVM, and the easiest way to introspect it is by adding a [Java Agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) to your app. This works because it is running inside the dyno along side your app. This is what New Relic's agent does and the information is collected and sent to their service, but if you're interested in making your own, its totally possible (but could be a bit of work).

To get started, you might want to take a look at the [`heroku-javaagent`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-javaagent), which is a very simple Java Agent that prints out vital stats (e.g. threads, memory, etc) about the JVM periodically into the log stream. This might be enough for you as is, but you could always tweak it for your what information you are trying to gather. Also, you could have it directly send the information to your dashboard or you could [consume the log stream](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/3/19/log2viz). To get started with it, take a look at the [Memory logging agent](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues#memory-logging-agent) section of the [Troubleshooting Memory Issues in Java Applications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues) article.